# Is this possible to call simple JS method from Angular JS controller method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have a controller on **controller.js** file.

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function (data) {
        alert("---" + data);
        // Test(); Calling java script method
    };
 });
```

In other file **common.js** we have defined

```
function Test()
{
  alert("Test Method is Calling");
 }
```

Both files are including in html, but we are not able to call legacy javascript code from controller method.

Kindly assist.

Comment: are you try something?

Comment: `$scope` you need to understand this. That is not in the scope of your angular controller.

Comment: @Jal - this not matter if function global

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine, make sure your other file is loaded:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function (data) {
        alert("---" + data);
        Test(); // Calling java script method
    };
 });


function Test()
{
  alert("Test Method is Calling");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyModule" ng-controller="MyController">
<button ng-click="myfunction('Hey')">Call extenal function</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i think this would not work if `Test` declared after calling. But for click event seems all should work :-)

Comment: @Grundy Actually it would, because of function hoisting. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vd66d6z9/   It's only important to have the definition in the same script block when hoisting. Try modifying my example from the answer, put the Test call just inside the controller, and you'll see it will work as well.

Comment: i just mean, that if `Test` defined in other file and `controller` function running before this file loaded and parsed, so we have a error :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's why I said `"make sure your other file is loaded"` :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend mixing AngularJS code with legacy JS code. In your case, if Test() is some kind of function that you are going to use often I would encapsulate it in a service and inject it into your controller

```
angular.module('MyModule')
    .factory('Utilities', function ($window) {
        return {
           Test : function() {
                $window.alert('Blah blah');
            }
        };
    });
```

And then in your controller

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, Utilities) {
    $scope.myfunction = function (data) {
        Utilities.Test();
    };
 });
```

This is pure AngularJS methodology

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use function of your external or internal java-script, but this is not good to mix the function within angular controller. 
If still you need it you can create a service and through service you can call the external java-script method.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('MyService', function() {

    this.callAlert = myTest();

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.callService = MyService.callAlert;
});


function myTest(){
  alert('Hello world');
}
```

Here's plunker link
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/w6XD3E1CGlDpc3eZQONo?p=preview)